# AJAX get request, refresh every 5 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I'm currently working on a project and can't really figure out how to refresh the AJAX request. 
At the moment my code work fine i can display all the Marker but i want to refresh it every 5 sec and receive the new one!
Below a copy of my script, I try to use setInterval without success jet!
Help on this will be really great. 
thanks again.

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}
window.loadGoogleMaps = function(){
    if(gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5207239719, -0.182568696184),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
    window.loadGoogleMaps();
});

$(window).load(function update () {


    $.ajax({
        url: 'get-last.php',
        success:function(data){
            //Loop through each location.
            $.each(data, function(){
                //Plot the location as a marker
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map
                });




            });
        } ,  complete: function() {
      setInterval(update, 1000);
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to wrap the `update()` function inside `setInterval()` instead of doing it on complete callback? Also I can't see where'd you define `map` variable

```
$(window).load(function(){
    update()
    setInterval(function(){
        update()
    }, 5000)
})

function update(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get-last.php',
        success:function(data){
            //Loop through each location.
            $.each(data, function(){
                //Plot the location as a marker
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map //is this been set globally?
                });
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, your function works only when i load the page and delete the marker loading for 5sec after than nothing more. any update?

Comment: @riccardotrevisan sorry forgot to add the function on page load. Added `update()` on load. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, now is working great. Thanks 'Chay22' you save my live. Realy nice job mate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);` function for this.
It will execute the function and after specific time recompute it

Comment: thanks, Nalin, your suggestion is good but is alerting me only the first time I load the page, not every 3 seconds. Am an i doing something wrong?

Comment: actually i replace setTimeout with setInterval and every 3 seconds a pop up say hello but not refreshing the marker